# Clojure: Deep-merge hash maps with dot-separated string keys

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for a function to achieve the following example result:

```
{"foo1"      "baz"
 "foo2.bar"  "baz"
 "foo2.bar2" "baz"
 "foo3_bar"  "baz"}
=>
{:foo1 "baz"
 :foo2 {:bar  "baz"
        :bar2 "baz"}
 :foo3 {:bar  "baz"}}
```

As one can see, it's a bit different from a classic [`deep-merge`](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/2ede388a9267d175bfaa7781ee9d57532eb4f20f/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/map_utils.clj) as the keys have to be `keyword`ized first in a way that dot- and underscore postfixes are converted to hash maps (instead of the usual `#[_\.]=> -`).

Comment: I think you expect the last entry to be [:foo2 {:bar "baz"}] right?

Comment: Yes, (almost) correct. I fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately having two different entries under :foo1 is not possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inspiration from @lgrapenthin I came up for this solution. It is on the upside short and concise and on the downside expensive (which is not to bad for my use case) and the overwriting strategy is determined by Clojure's hash map sorting (aka for user's undetermined):

```clj
(defn- deep-merge [& maps]
  (if (every? map? maps)
    (apply merge-with deep-merge maps)
    (last maps)))

(defn- str-keys-to-map [[k v]]
  (let [ks (map keyword (filter not-empty (string/split k #"[\._]")))]
    (when-not (empty? ks) (assoc-in {} ks v))))

(defn deep-keywordize-keys [m]
  (->> m (map str-keys-to-map) (apply deep-merge)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn parse-keys-and-merge
  [hm]
  (reduce-kv (fn [hm k v]
               (assoc-in hm (map keyword (clojure.string/split k #"[\._]"))
                         (if (map? v)
                           (parse-keys-and-merge v)
                           v)))
             {} hm))
```

This does not work for your hash-map because your hash-map does not clarify whether the entry for `:foo` should be `"baz"` or `{:bar "baz", :bar2 "baz"}`. With a fixed hash-map it works:

```
(parse-keys-and-merge {"foo2_bar" "baz", "foo.bar2" "baz", "foo.bar" "baz"})
;; {:foo {:bar "baz", :bar2 "baz"}, :foo2 {:bar "baz"}}
```

Comment: You are correct. I went ahead of myself where I want to apply this along the `(merge)` function. I updated the input and resutl hash map to result my need more clearly.

Comment: Where is `(reduce-kv)` declared?

Comment: `clojure.core` (http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduce-kv)

Comment: I just tried the `(parse-keys-and-merge)` and it fails in one specific case: `{"foo.bar" "hello", "foo.bar.baz" "world"}`

Comment: Yes, because you can not simultaneously have a string and a hash-map as an entry for `foo.bar`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a function like this one.
Please note that it could be optimized to do tail recursion.

```
        (defn deep-hashmap-merge
          [ m ]
          (let
            [
            tget (fn [r k d]
                    (let
                      [ t (get r k d)]
                      (if (associative? t) t d))) 
            get-keylist-value (fn [r [k & ks] kv]
                              (if (nil? ks)
                                (assoc r k kv)
                                (assoc r k (get-keylist-value (tget r k {}) ks kv))))     
            ]
              (reduce #(get-keylist-value %1 (map keyword (clojure.string/split (first %2) #"[_\.]")) ( second %2)) {} m)
            )
          )
```

And the output would then be :

```
              user=> (deep-hashmap-merge 
              #_=> {"foo"      "baz"
              #_=>  "foo.bar"  "baz"
              #_=>  "foo.bar2" "baz"
              #_=>  "foo2_bar" "baz"})

              {:foo {:bar "baz", :bar2 "baz"}, :foo2 {:bar "baz"}}
```

Comment: //added keyword (keys were strings)